# Pass up child component's config to parent

Tags: extjs, extjs4

Normally, to define a grid type, I do something like this:

```
Ext.define('MyApp.view.MyGrid', {
  extend: 'Ext.grid.Panel',
  alias: 'widget.myGrid',
  store: 'MyStore',
  columns: [...],
}
```

and then I add it to a container or layout via its xtype, 'myGrid'.

What I want to do is define a reusable custom component that either extends `Ext.grid.Panel` or accepts the same configs (such as columns), but is really a container that contains a grid and other stuff.

```
Ext.define('MyApp.components.ContainedGrid', {
  extend: 'Ext.container.Container' //or Ext.grid.Panel, whatever works
  alias: 'widget.containedGrid',
  layout: 'card',
  items: [
    {someObject}, //doesn't matter what this is
    {aGrid}, //the grid that should receive the configs from the caller
  ],
}
```

Ideally, this component could be configured like a regular `Ext.grid.Panel` object, and those configurations should be really apply to the grid defined second in the items array.

In other words, something like the following should render a window containing a card layout, where the second card should be the grid, with the columns & store provided to the container.

```
Ext.create('Ext.window.Window',  {
  title: 'hi',
  layout: 'fit',
  items: {
    xtype: 'containedGrid',
    store: myStore,
    columns: [...],
  },
});
```

Logically, I just want to say that the configs provided to the container apply to one of its components, but I don't know how to execute that.  Any thoughts?

**Edit:**
To be succinct, what I'm trying to do is create a component that is configured just like a grid, but is really a container that includes a grid, along with some other stuff.  This component will be used several times, so I'd like to package it as a reusable component.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Define a property for the gridconfig

```
Ext.define('MyApp.components.ContainedGrid', {
  extend: 'Ext.container.Container' //or Ext.grid.Panel, whatever works
  alias: 'widget.containedGrid',
  layout: 'card',
  /**
   * @cfg {object} gridCfg
   */

  initComponent: function(){
     var gridCfg = { xtype: 'grid' };
     if(this.gridCfg)
          gridCfg = Ext.apply(gridCfg ,this.gridCfg);
     if (this.items) // we assume if set it will be always array!
          this.items.push(gridCfg);
     else
          this.items = [gridCfg];
     delete this.gridCfg; // we no longer need this property here
     this.callParent(arguments);
  }
}
```

And the usecase:

```
Ext.create('Ext.window.Window',  {
  title: 'hi',
  layout: 'fit',
  items: {
    xtype: 'containedGrid',
    gridCfg: {
       store: myStore,
       columns: [...]
    }
  },
});
```

**Update**

I think I now understand what you are looking for. To register listeners directly onto the container you need to relay the events. I've made a example that at least relay the events of the view (which should be most). You will be able to relay also events of the table and the features (features first after rendering). Here's a **[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sran/9J6Ds/1/)** that print all events from the container into the console.

```
Ext.define('Ext.ux.ContainedGrid', {
      extend: 'Ext.container.Container',
      alias: 'widget.containedGrid',
      layout: 'card',
      /**
       * @cfg {object} gridCfg
       */

      /**
       * @private {object} grid
       */
      initComponent: function(){
         var me = this,
             grid;
         // provide some default settings for the grid here, 
         // which can be overriden by each instance
         var gridCfg = { }; // the defaulttype is defined on the componentmanager call
         me.gridCfg = me.gridCfg ? Ext.apply(gridCfg ,me.gridCfg) : gridCfg;

         me.grid = me.getGrid();

         if (me.items && Ext.isArray(me.items)) 
              me.items.push(me.grid);
         else if(me.items)
              me.items = [me.items, me.grid];
         else
              me.items = [me.grid];
         delete me.gridCfg; // we no longer need this property here
         // Relay events from the View whether it be a LockingView, or a regular GridView
         this.relayEvents(me.grid, [
                /**
                 * @event beforeitemmousedown
                 * @inheritdoc Ext.view.View#beforeitemmousedown
                 */
                'beforeitemmousedown',
                /**
                 * @event beforeitemmouseup
                 * @inheritdoc Ext.view.View#beforeitemmouseup
                 */
                'beforeitemmouseup',
                /**
                 * @event beforeitemmouseenter
                 * @inheritdoc Ext.view.View#beforeitemmouseenter
                 */
                'beforeitemmouseenter',
                /**
                 * @event beforeitemmouseleave
                 * @inheritdoc Ext.view.View#beforeitemmouseleave
                 */
                'beforeitemmouseleave',
                /**
                 * @event beforeitemclick
                 * @inheritdoc Ext.view.View#beforeitemclick
                 */
                'beforeitemclick',
                /**
                 * @event beforeitemdblclick
                 * @inheritdoc Ext.view.View#beforeitemdblclick
                 */
                'beforeitemdblclick',
                /**
                 * @event beforeitemcontextmenu
                 * @inheritdoc Ext.view.View#beforeitemcontextmenu
                 */
                'beforeitemcontextmenu',
                /**
                 * @event itemmousedown
                 * @inheritdoc Ext.view.View#itemmousedown
                 */
                'itemmousedown',
                /**
                 * @event itemmouseup
                 * @inheritdoc Ext.view.View#itemmouseup
                 */
                'itemmouseup',
                /**
                 * @event itemmouseenter
                 * @inheritdoc Ext.view.View#itemmouseenter
                 */
                'itemmouseenter',
                /**
                 * @event itemmouseleave
                 * @inheritdoc Ext.view.View#itemmouseleave
                 */
                'itemmouseleave',
                /**
                 * @event itemclick
                 * @inheritdoc Ext.view.View#itemclick
                 */
                'itemclick',
                /**
                 * @event itemdblclick
                 * @inheritdoc Ext.view.View#itemdblclick
                 */
                'itemdblclick',
                /**
                 * @event itemcontextmenu
                 * @inheritdoc Ext.view.View#itemcontextmenu
                 */
                'itemcontextmenu',
                /**
                 * @event beforecontainermousedown
                 * @inheritdoc Ext.view.View#beforecontainermousedown
                 */
                'beforecontainermousedown',
                /**
                 * @event beforecontainermouseup
                 * @inheritdoc Ext.view.View#beforecontainermouseup
                 */
                'beforecontainermouseup',
                /**
                 * @event beforecontainermouseover
                 * @inheritdoc Ext.view.View#beforecontainermouseover
                 */
                'beforecontainermouseover',
                /**
                 * @event beforecontainermouseout
                 * @inheritdoc Ext.view.View#beforecontainermouseout
                 */
                'beforecontainermouseout',
                /**
                 * @event beforecontainerclick
                 * @inheritdoc Ext.view.View#beforecontainerclick
                 */
                'beforecontainerclick',
                /**
                 * @event beforecontainerdblclick
                 * @inheritdoc Ext.view.View#beforecontainerdblclick
                 */
                'beforecontainerdblclick',
                /**
                 * @event beforecontainercontextmenu
                 * @inheritdoc Ext.view.View#beforecontainercontextmenu
                 */
                'beforecontainercontextmenu',
                /**
                 * @event containermouseup
                 * @inheritdoc Ext.view.View#containermouseup
                 */
                'containermouseup',
                /**
                 * @event containermouseover
                 * @inheritdoc Ext.view.View#containermouseover
                 */
                'containermouseover',
                /**
                 * @event containermouseout
                 * @inheritdoc Ext.view.View#containermouseout
                 */
                'containermouseout',
                /**
                 * @event containerclick
                 * @inheritdoc Ext.view.View#containerclick
                 */
                'containerclick',
                /**
                 * @event containerdblclick
                 * @inheritdoc Ext.view.View#containerdblclick
                 */
                'containerdblclick',
                /**
                 * @event containercontextmenu
                 * @inheritdoc Ext.view.View#containercontextmenu
                 */
                'containercontextmenu',
                /**
                 * @event selectionchange
                 * @inheritdoc Ext.selection.Model#selectionchange
                 */
                'selectionchange',
                /**
                 * @event beforeselect
                 * @inheritdoc Ext.selection.RowModel#beforeselect
                 */
                'beforeselect',
                /**
                 * @event select
                 * @inheritdoc Ext.selection.RowModel#select
                 */
                'select',
                /**
                 * @event beforedeselect
                 * @inheritdoc Ext.selection.RowModel#beforedeselect
                 */
                'beforedeselect',
                /**
                 * @event deselect
                 * @inheritdoc Ext.selection.RowModel#deselect
                 */
                'deselect'
            ]);
         me.callParent(arguments);
      },
      getGrid: function() {
         if(this.grid)
             return this.grid;
         return this.grid = Ext.ComponentManager.create(this.gridCfg,'grid');;
      }

});
```

Comment: This seems to be working very well.  One caveat worth noting:  1) I need to set an itemId inside gridCfg in order for the Controller to listen to events against #itemId, since the xtype 'containedGrid' will not be unique, and the xtype of the outer component will not refer to the grid.

Comment: @romacafe Well, there is nothing that hinder you doing so. Maybe I didn't get you, where do you see any downside with this? basically you will just need to provide a unique path which makes it only necessary to place the itemId on the grid if you have two of them in the same container, otherwise I would try to identify the container. And it only need to be a itemId if you ever want to use that component feature otherwise you could use any, even custom property to query by.

Comment: I don't want to sound unappreciative, this was tremendously helpful!  The most ideal solution would allow the developer to use it *exactly* the same way as a standard grid, changing only the xtype, but I feel like its impractical.  (You'd have to extend grid and then muck with its own layout and/or items collection, I guess, but all my attempts have been unsuccessful so far).  Requiring a nested config and an itemId are relatively small concessions, and the best option I have at the moment.

Comment: @romacafe You got me wrong here, you didn't sound unappreciative. I just don't understand where you see (saw?) the problem with this approach. That may be because I don't know the goal you're trying to achieve. And you can use is as a grid, you will just need to access the grid first, like the way you need to first get the view from the grid for some operations. Dunno if this helps you but I will extends my answer which hopefully get's nearer to what you are looking for.

Comment: @romacafe See my edit. I think this will come closer to what you are looking for.

Answer (score 5):

Override the initComponent method:

```
Ext.define('MyWindow', {
    extend: 'Ext.window.Window',
    layout: 'fit',
    title: 'Foo',

    initComponent: function(){
        this.items = {
            xtype: 'grid',
            store: this.store,
            columns: this.columns    
        };
        this.callParent();
    }
});

Ext.onReady(function(){
    new MyWindow({
        width: 200,
        height: 200,
        autoShow: true,
        store: {
            fields: ['name'],
            data: [{
                name: 'Name 1'
            }]
        },
        columns: [{
            dataIndex: 'name',
            text: 'Name'
        }]
    });
});
```

Comment: Thank you for this, it is extremely helpful.  It works perfectly as long as all I care about are the store & columns configs.  Unfortunately, if I try to configure the grid for editing (setting selType & plugins), then I get an error "Cannot read property 'selModel' of undefined".  The undefined variable is the grid's view.  I tried also copying the view down, and the selModel, but its getting a) too complicated and b) never worked anyway.  I'd really like a way to copy everything, including functions.  For all intents and purposes, the contained grid IS the grid the user configured...

Comment: Another approach could be that the reusable component IS a grid (extends Ext.grid.Panel), but at some point (initComponent?) it removes itself from its parent container, puts itself into a new container, and adds that container back to the parent, in the same position.  Could something like that work?